# Create neo4j graph database from python using html forms

Tags: html, neo4j, py2neo

Hi i'm very new to neo4j i need to know how to create nodes and properties of graph using html forms by using py2neo and neo4j and how to add auto id's to the nodes

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,url_for,json,jsonify
from py2neo import neo4j,Graph,Node,Relationship,cypher
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase


app = Flask(__name__)
gdb = GraphDatabase("http://neo4j:duke@localhost:7474/db/data")
graph=Graph("http://neo4j:duke@localhost:7474/db/data")
@app.route('/')
def index():
    results = graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n")
'''print "gyktdjxdhgfcvkjbljkfr",result'''
    return results.json
@app.route('/hello')
def create():
    return "f"


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched Google for relevant articles or tutorials? Do you have some code you've already put together that you need help with?

Comment: i tried creating nodes,properties and relationships via console and i have written some python code to view all the nodes but i cant view the nodes in browser by using return cmd but i print all nodes in terminal using print  i have used flask server

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the code you have so far, please? Your question as it stands can't be answered.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this blog post by Nicole for some insight:

http://neo4j.com/blog/building-python-web-application-using-flask-neo4j/

code is on github:

https://github.com/nicolewhite/neo4j-flask

You don't need auto-incrementing id's like in a relational database.
Just use the person's login for that and use `MERGE`

See. http://neo4j.com/developer/cypher